# Hiding App (or running in background) without using service

Tags: android

I am working on using the USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED intent on an app. The app works fine, but I would like to open it with another app to start using the device.

I'm wanting the app to launch either hidden or in the background (not launch on top of the already running app). I've seen some use services for this, but it looks like USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED (and the other usb intents/permissions) don't work on a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using an activity with the NoDisplay theme.

Answer (score 1):

Have your broadcast receiver call the service when it receives that particular intent action and then start your service.

### Update

Read the great link provided by CommonsWare:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

Comment: Actually, `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` is an activity action, if I am reading the docs correctly. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

Comment: Hmm, last time I used that particular action i'm fairly certain I was in a broadcast receiver. To my understanding of the OS back from gingerbread.. The StorageManager is the first to receive that USB has been plugged in and then it dispatches the message to all listeners. If I remember correctly a broadcast receiver should be able to receive it. However; this there is a little bias (potentially) because I was working at the platform level when I was dealing with it. But it should work, I don't see why it would be only limited to activities.

Comment: I'm using similar code to this in the project, but I have tried to put the intent-filter for USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED in a service before with no success. I'll need to be able to access that intent, as well as connect to the usb.

Comment: So did you receive the intent and then pass that intent over to the service? How did that work? Did you run into permission problems with that, in terms of the usb interface itself?

Comment: No one said to put it in a service. I **said** to have a broadcast receiver catch the intent and THEN do something with it. Its just message passing to check if USB is connected. IE. pass an extra from your BRC to your Service and then handle it.